# Is it ever been considered the possibility of "accepting two Answers"?

Tags: feature-request

A person provided a good answer which I accepted, then later on another excellent question appears which deserves "accepting" but am unable to.

Any movement on allowing "two" accepted answers?

Comment: I think that the tag ([meta-tag:accepted-answer]) would be suitable here. (I do not have sufficient reputation to edit on meta - so I've mentioned this in a comment instead.)

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, for a while they had some idea of "versioning" in which we might be able to do that, but the feature never really took off